# Regex doesn't work in google analytics custom segmentation

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to extract string matched with `r'^/study/[0-9]+/'` by URI in Google Analytics custom segmentation.
To extract specific string, i applied `^/study/[0-9]+/` regex to `page`. but it's doesn't work.
it doesn't filter `/study/?filter_by=category&category=job`. other things are same too.
What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

Could use an or to include a literal ? and then an | to include your other filter:

```
^/study/\?.*|[0-9]+/
```

So the RegEx I gave you was written to include a ? and anything after that ?; I read your question wrong. :)

Are you trying to create an advanced segment using this RegEx? If so, we ran into this issue a few weeks ago and submitted a bug to Google. They got back to us with this:

This is working as intended. When you create a segment based on a page regex it will match any session that has at least one page matching that regex. It then proceeds to include that session in the segment along with all other pages it visited, no matter if they match the regex or not.

If you just want to see the pages that match that regex than forget about custom segments.

Go into the Page report and do a report filter.

I believe it was @Eduardo who wrote this.

Comment: regex does work on other concepts (e.g language) but not on `page`